# match and term giving different results on text field elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning elasticsearch-7.4.0 and working with basic queries.

I have a `product` index which has a field `name` with the following mapping:

```
"name" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  }
}
```

When I am executing the term query to match documents with name "`Wine - Ice Wine`".

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size" : 1000,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Wine - Ice Wine"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output I am getting:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

When I am running match query:

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size" : 1000,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Wine - Ice Wine"
    }
  }
}
```

The output I am getting:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 75,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 12.354952,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "product",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "403",
        "_score" : 12.354952,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Wine - Ice Wine",
          "price" : 127,
          "in_stock" : 26,
          "sold" : 334,
          "tags" : [
            "Alcohol",
            "Wine"
          ],
          "description" : "Nulla neque libero, convallis eget, eleifend luctus, ultricies eu, nibh. Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum.",
          "is_active" : true,
          "created" : "2010/04/12"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As mentioned, term level queries look for **exact** match.
 
So, I am specifying the entire string in the search query.
 
Both the queries should return the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Term queries are to be used on [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) fields in order to get the exact match.

From the above link, we have the below for `keyword` datatype:

> They are typically used for filtering (Find me all blog posts where
>   status is published), for sorting, and for aggregations. Keyword
>   fields are only searchable by their exact value.

From your mapping, the field `name` has sibling field which is `name.keyword` which is of type `keyword`.

Modify your term query to make use of it as below and it would give you the desired result.

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size" : 1000,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": {                  <---- Note this
        "value": "Wine - Ice Wine"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While on the other hand, the `match` query you make use of on `text` field goes through the [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) phase.

Basically when you have a field of text type and when you ingest a document it converts the sentences into tokens, converts them into small case letters and thereby stores in the inverted index. This would be [index time analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html#_index_time_analysis)

The same thing happens when you use a match query i.e. whatever you add in the query part, it breaks down into individual words or tokens and searches them in inverted index. This is [search time analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html#_search_time_analysis).

The analysis is done by concept called [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html). By default it makes use of [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

I'd suggest you go through the links to understand more on this.

Hope this helps!